# What is [:,:-1] in python?

Tags: python

I just started learning ML myself in python.
I didn't understand a passage in the code and would be happy if you made it clear to me what he was saying.
Plus I don't know what `[:, -1]` and `[:,: - 1]` do

```
inputs = training_data[:,:-1]
outputs = training_data[:, -1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1011724 or just google slicing in numpy

Comment: This is not just about slicing, notice the comma...

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't address a `,` in the slice, but that's simply enough; `__getitem__` receives a tuple of `slice` objects, rather than a single `slice` object.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez the comma just means one of the slice parameters is a tuple.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, it's a tuple of slices.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509377/1126841), at least, to the proposed duplicate addresses commas.

Comment: @chepner how does that parse? To get a slice you need both the opening and close brackets, don't you?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html; the relevant non-terminals are `trailer`, `subscriptlist`, `subscript`, and `sliceop`. In a nutshell, a subscript is a comma-separate list of `:` expressions.

Comment: The trailer `[:, :-1]` generates two `slice` objects, `slice(None,None,None)` and `slice(None, -1, None)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[:, :]` literally means `[all rows, all columns]`.

Indexing in python starts from `0` when you go from the first element to the last, but it starts from `-1` when you start from the last element.

So, when you do `[:, -1]` it means you are taking all the rows and only the last column. `-1` represents the last column.

When you do `[:, :-1]`, it means you are taking all the rows and all the columns except the last column.

Now, when you do `training_data[:, -1]` it means from the dataframe `training_date`, you are using all the rows and only the last column. Similarly `training_data[:, :-1]` means all the rows and all the columns except the last column.

**But:**

You might run into a slicing problem if you do `training_data[:, -1]`. Since you are using integers to slice the `df`, it is always better to use the [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method.

This tutorial [How do I select multiple rows and columns from a pandas DataFrame?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvpNA7bC8cs) explains everything clearly. Have a look at it.

example:
[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

```
x = np.random.rand(3,2)
x
array([[0.55424444, 0.86283166],
       [0.11931308, 0.43853805],
       [0.13662337, 0.06383871]])
n = x[:, -1]
n
array([0.86283166, 0.43853805, 0.06383871])
```